# react native turn object array into string array

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native

I am searching for a while now, how I could achieve to turn objects arrays into an array with only values. For example, I have an array with several Restaurants and within these restaurants there is a key named category. Category could have multiple values like Sushi, Chinese, asian. I would like to go trough all object and reduce my array from:

```
[{
      id: '1',
      title: 'Italian Dream',
      category: 'Pizza, Pasta, Snack',
      opening_hours: '08:00-24:00',
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      title: 'Turkish Man',
      category: 'Döner, Pizza, Lahmacun',
      opening_hours: '08:00-24:00',
    }]



to 



[ Pasta, Snack, Döner, Pizza, Lahmacun]
```

Would be glad if anybody could give me any advice.

Cheers

Comment: [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is used to transform data in an array in JavaScript.

Comment: So you want to extract all categories from all restaurants array to another array?

Comment: Yes, I want to extract all categories to a new array

Comment: A better and mode useful model would be to have an array of strings for `category` vs. a string that needs to be `.split`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Since `category` is a string and not an array of strings, we need to `.split(', ')`
2. Since we have multiple categories per data item, we can use `.flatMap` to "combine" or flatten that what would have been an array of arrays
3. We can use `new Set(...)` to get a unique list of string values
4. And finally use `Array.from(...)` to convert the `Set` to an `Array`.

```js
const data = [{
    id: '1',
    title: 'Italian Dream',
    category: 'Pizza, Pasta, Snack',
    opening_hours: '08:00-24:00',
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Turkish Man',
    category: 'Döner, Pizza, Lahmacun',
    opening_hours: '08:00-24:00',
  }
]

const categories = Array.from(new Set(data.flatMap(x => x.category.split(', '))))
console.log(categories)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop your array and use split function to extract categories from your string.

```
let newArray = [];
oldArray.forEach(restaurant => {
   newArray.push(...restaurant.category.split(', '));
});

// Here newArray contains categories with duplicate values

// You can use Set to avoid duplicate values.
newArray = [...new Set(newArray)];
```